# resizing video with html in rmarkdown presentation

Tags: html, video, r-markdown

I'm using the following snippet to embed a local video in a presentation made with xaringan in rmarkdown:

```
<video>
<source src="video_name.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

The video works fine, but it runs off the bottom of the slide (i.e., it's too tall), and I cannot get any resizing to stick. I've tried using percentages

```
<video>
<source src="video_name.mp4" type="video/mp4" height="50%">
</video>
```

And absolute size

```
<video>
<source src="video_name.mp4" type="video/mp4" height="100">
</video>
```

And the video height does not change. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The height argument controls the size of the container, so in this case, that would go into the `video` tag:

```
<video width='50%'>
<source src="video_name.mp4" type="video/mp4" >
</video>
```